# Realloc an array of structs that contain dynamically sized char pointers

Tags: c, dynamic, struct, realloc

The point of this assignment is to read in a line from a file containing a city state followed by two lines that contain latitude and longitude coordinates. Then we need dynamically allocate structs exactly as they are written below to store these coordinates. Finally we export the landmarks to a KML format used by google earth.

At this point I can correctly write the KML from my structs. However that took a couple of dirty for loops in my grow_whole function (seen below). The issue is when I am freeing all the allocated pointers later. (Trust me it exists ill paste it in order below). I am pretty sure the problem is heap corruption. However ive been working on this way too long and I feel it could be simpler.

The file format. (There is like 150 of these.)

```
city, state
40 30 N
40 20 W
```

Wholesome_t is just a container that will hold information on the amount of landmark structs as well as the pointer to the first landmark. Landmark_t holds pointers to chars that are allocated with exactly the amount of space they need to contain their parsed city name and such.

```
struct landmark_t {
char *city;
char *state;
char *country;
float longitude;
float latitude;
};

struct wholesome_t {
struct landmark_t *landmarks;
int landcount;
int landmax;
};
```

Below is the chunk of code that handles reading lines and sending them to the correct parser.

Initially wholesome is malloc'd and the landmarks pointer is set to NULL.
Then we malloc space for 2 landmark structs and begin the while loop below.

```
struct landmark_t *land = NULL;
int coorflag = 0;
int flagcount = 0;
//Parse lines
while(fgets(buf, LEN, in)){
    //Does that thing where we realloc
    if(whole->landcount == whole->landmax){
        grow_whole(whole);
    }

    //remove trailing newline
    buf[strcspn(buf, "\n")] = 0;

    if(!coorflag){//Check to see if we are on a flag or coordinate
        //set land to be the pointer to our next empty landmark struct
        land = whole->landmarks + (sizeof(struct landmark_t) * whole->landcount);
        set_city_state_country(buf, land);
        coorflag = 1; //Set flag to get a coordinate line next
    }else{//We are on a coordinate line which will use 
          //the same land struct pointer as above
        if(!flagcount){//Have we seen a coordinate line already?
            land->latitude = number_muncher(buf);
            flagcount = 1;
        }else{//We have seen a coordinate line
            land->longitude = number_muncher(buf); 
            //We are done filling this structure. Reset flags and move to the next.
            flagcount = 0;
            coorflag = 0;
            whole->landcount++;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is in grow_whole. I had a problem earlier where after running realloc the first landmark structure would contain the correctly assigned pointers but anything after it until somewhere near the end of the file all of the pointers for city, state, and country as well as longitude and latitude would be nulled out. I added the for loops that save all of our pointers to arrays before we realloc and then rewrite those pointers back to the correct structure.

```
void grow_whole(struct wholesome_t *whole)
{
//First collect all of the pointers inside our current landmark structs.
struct landmark_t *land = NULL;
char *city[whole->landcount];
char *state[whole->landcount];
char *country[whole->landcount];
float longitude[whole->landcount];
float latitude[whole->landcount];
for (int i = 0; i < whole->landcount; i++){
    land = whole->landmarks + (sizeof(struct landmark_t) * i);
    city[i] = land->city;
    state[i] = land->state;
    country[i] = land->country;
    longitude[i] = land->longitude;
    latitude[i] = land->latitude;
}
land = realloc(whole->landmarks, (GROW + whole->landmax) * sizeof(struct landmark_t));
if(land == NULL){
    printf("Error in grow_whole.\n");
    return;
}else{whole->landmarks = land;}
//Update landmax to represent aftergrow.
whole->landmax = GROW + whole->landmax;
//Refill all of the re allocated structs with their pointers.
for (int i = 0; i < whole->landcount; i++){
    land = whole->landmarks + (sizeof(struct landmark_t) * i);
    land->city = city[i];
    land->state = state[i];
    land->country = country[i];
    land->longitude = longitude[i];
    land->latitude = latitude[i];
}
//Fill two new structs with blank data.
for(int i = whole->landcount; i < whole->landmax; i++){
    land = whole->landmarks + (sizeof(struct landmark_t) * i);
    empty_fill(land);
}
return;
}
```

Immediatly after the while loop above we run

```
fclose(in);
char *s = argv[1];
s = strtok(s, ".");
s = strncat(s, ".kml", 4);
FILE *out = fopen(s, "w");
//Finally done lets write some KML
kml_begin(out);
for (int i=0; i < whole->landcount; i++){
    land = whole->landmarks + (sizeof(struct landmark_t) * i);
    kml_placemark(out, i, land);
}
kml_end(out);
fclose(out);
tea_party(whole);//free land
free(whole->landmarks);
free(whole);
```

Which gets to kml_end(out). (I know because I have a properly formatted with correct values .kml file) But during tea_party I get a seg_fault.

```
void tea_party(struct wholesome_t *whole)
{
    struct landmark_t *land = NULL; 
    for (int i = 0; i < whole->landcount; i++){
        land = whole->landmarks + (sizeof(struct landmark_t) * i);
        printf("here\n");
        free(land->city);
        printf("here2\n");
        free(land->state);
        printf("here3\n");
       free(land->country);
    }
return;
}
```

It occurs for our second landmark struct.

```
land = whole->landmarks + sizeof(struct landmark_t)
```

And happens at free(land->state) (because I see here 1-3 for the first struct and then here 1-2 before the seg fault.)

Even if I try to print land->state right before the seg fault it just moves the seg fault up.

Answer (score 0):

When doing pointer arithmetic, you don't have to scale the offset by `sizeof(struct landmark_t)` - the compiler already does that for you!

If you have a pointer `p` into an array, the next array element is at `p + 1`. It's that simple.

Also, you seems to create a record of arrays, when you should probably create an array of records. But that is a different problem.